# Skobbler current street name,currentAdviceInstruction and audio advices not working

Tags: ios, skmaps

I am currently developing a turn by turn navigation application and I use the API Skobbler , I managed to integrate , but when I made real-time tests I noticed that I don't get information from callbacks, like :

```
-(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didUpdateFilteredAudioAdvices:(NSArray *)audioAdvices{

 NSLog(@"audio advices: %@",audioAdvices);
```

}
    -(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeCurrentStreetName:(NSString *)currentStreetName streetType:(SKStreetType)streetType countryCode:(NSString *)countryCode{

```
NSLog(@"street name: %@,%d,%@",currentStreetName,streetType,countryCode );
// NSLog(@"routing service array: %@",routingService.visualAdviceConfigurations);
```

}
    -(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService  didChangeCurrentAdviceImage:(UIImage *)adviceImage withLastAdvice:(BOOL)isLastAdvice{

```
NSLog(@"image changed");
}
- (void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeCurrentAdviceInstruction:(NSString *)currentAdviceInstruction nextAdviceInstruction:(NSString *)nextAdviceInstruction{

NSLog(@"current instruction: %@",currentAdviceInstruction);
```

}

The only callbacks i get are :

- (void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeCurrentSpeed:(double)speed{

  NSLog(@"speed: %f",speed);

}
    - (void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeDistanceToDestination:(int)distance withFormattedDistance:(NSString *)formattedDistance{

```
NSLog(@"distance: %@",formattedDistance);
```

}

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using for starting the navigation service (are you navigating on a route or just free drive?)

Comment: I'am navigated on a route, this is how i did: SKRouteSettings* route = [[SKRouteSettings alloc]init];
    route.startCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude,userLocation.coordinate.longitude);    route.destinationCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.8215965,2.3715504);
    
    [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] calculateRoute:route];

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour in the demo project? For example I'm looking at RoutingViewController and there I get all the correct callbacks during navigation.

Answer (score 1):

`- (void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo:(SKRouteInformation*)routeInformation{
    NSLog(@"Route is calculated.");
    [routingService zoomToRouteWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero]; // zooming to currrent route
    //NSArray *adviceList = [routingService routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat:SKDistanceFormatMetric]; // array of SKRouteAdvice
    NSLog(@"routing distance : %d",routeInformation.distance);
    NSLog(@"routing time : %d",routeInformation.estimatedTime);
    SKNavigationSettings* navSettings = [SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings];
    navSettings.navigationType=SKNavigationTypeReal;
    navSettings.distanceFormat=SKDistanceFormatMetric;
    [SKRoutingService sharedInstance].mapView.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode3D;
    [[SKRoutingService     sharedInstance]startNavigationWithSettings:navSettings];
}`This is how i start navigation:

Comment: One remark - the navigation type is set to real - this means that you will actually need to start moving on the route for the callbacks to be triggered - if you want to run a simulation, use     navSettings.navigationType=SKNavigationTypeSimulation;

Comment: Using the provided code snippet in our demo app works. Please see the class at https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgfannynp7bhbid/RoutingViewController.m?dl=0 and replace it in the demo app. The callbacks are coming in simulation & real drive situation too.